# Creating Array for Sections in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I'm creating a tableview from a plist which contains an array of 6 dictionaries.
One of the fields in the dictionaries is LastUpdatedDate, which I'd like to use as the table section value.

I'm trying to populate the section array using the code below, but nothing is added.
Any ideas?

```
BOOL found;
for (NSDictionary *document in documents){

    NSString *date = [document objectForKey:@"LastUpdatedDate"];

    found = NO;

    for (NSString *str in sections){

        if ([sections containsObject:str])
        {
            found = YES;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {

        [sections addObject:date];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ... you are looping through all strings in sections, and for each string in sections you check whether it is part of sections - of course it is always TRUE and found therefore YES.

You probably want to check whether **date** is contained in **sections** ;-).

Comment: Well spotted; it's been a long day!

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop makes no sense. You check if every String from the sections-Array is in the sections-Array, that is always true! It is enough to check if the date is in the sections-Array

```
[sections containsObject:date]
```

Did you get a valid date-String that should be added to the sections-Array? How do you know if the sections are empty? What is the count of the sections-array?

```
[sections count]
```

Well the addObject-call looks good...